# XCode crashes when I try to drag and drop an IB Outlet

Tags: xcode, uiview, iboutlet

When I try to drag and drop an IB outlet from a UIView into my ViewController.swift, XCode crashes (when I press OK after typing a name for the IBOutlet).
A popup appears saying: "XCode quit unexpectedly": Ignore, report, reopen.
The report says lots of verbose, the most notable warnings are these:

```
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): +[IDESwiftSourceCodeGenerator isTeardownCounterpart:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1159415c0
prepareToAddSourceCodeForCounterparts:documentLocationForCounterpartBlock:addSourceCodeForCounterpartBlock:options:error:] (in IDEKit)
  8  0x000000011588a13f -[IDESwiftSourceCodeGenerator prepareToAddPropertyWithName:type:inClassItem:options:error:] (in IDELanguageSupportUI)
```

I have other IBOutlets working well for UILabels and a Table View, so I do not understand, why this happens.

I am fairly new to Xcode, if you need any additional info to detect what is going wrong, I will gladly provide it.
Already tried the usual Clean, Rebuild, Reopen, Restart, and Simulator reset just in case....

Comment: Your project might be corrupt.  I know it's a PITA but it happens sometimes.  You might try rebuilding your project from scratch.  Also try the drag and drop with someone else's Mac.

Comment: Try dropping to a different line usually  to a blank line with no other line in top and bottom of it

Comment: @zellb Sorry, XCode is still crashing

Comment: Unfortunately this is between you and Apple. Stack Overflow is about programming, not about some app that is crashing on your Mac — even, alas, if that app happens to be Xcode.

Comment: The IDE directly affects programming, even, alas, if you have no clue about what the solution is. @matt

Comment: @matt there are 98k posts tagged with Xcode, i guess none of them are relevant then?

Comment: @BROK3NS0UL How to use Xcode to program, relevant. Xcode is crashing, not relevant (but file a bug with Apple).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, I tried different ways towards desired purpose. 
I discovered an esoteric workaround:

1-Type this in the .swift file:

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
```

2-Do the drag and drop FROM the line of code above TO the UIView in the story board, NOT the other way around, otherwise: XCode will crash.

3-Voila! Bug evaded.

Comment: Thanks, I was having the same issue. Since updating to Xcode 7.3 it is so buggy ....

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot!

Comment: Experiencing this in 9.0.1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous crashes for me also on Xcode 9.4.1 and 10_GM - after linking IBOutlet with XIB.
Solution: clean up Derived data **/Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData**.
Based on: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76730